# strange compilation error about pthreadtypes.h: 'section' attribute

Tags: compiler-errors, clang

I met a very strange error during compile my code using clang.

here is my command

```
$clang -c -emit-llvm -I/OP-TEE/op-tee-os/optee_os/lib/libutee/include/ -I/OP-TEE/op-tee-os/optee_os/lib/libutils/ext/include/ test_function_call_ta.c
```

and here is the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:270:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h:200:5: error: 'section' attribute only applies to functions, methods,
      properties, and global variables
  } __data;
    ^
/opensource_projects/OP-TEE/op-tee-os/optee_os/lib/libutils/ext/include/compiler.h:51:17: note: expanded
      from macro '__data'
#define __data          __section(".data")
                        ^
/opensource_projects/OP-TEE/op-tee-os/optee_os/lib/libutils/ext/include/compiler.h:50:37: note: expanded
      from macro '__section'
#define __section(x)    __attribute__((section(x)))
```

I was wondering why this error is happening, because I did not use any section attributes in the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this issue. The reason is that I import a wrong header file by "-I". The correct one should in another folder...